# Python coverage shows missing on imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, coverage.py

I can see the following code coverage

[image]

Now I know that this is because `import` is happening before test starts. But how do I get around it. Also, since i have moved my import into the `setUp` function, it should be ideally called for all my test cases.

[image]

> Note: I'm using python3's unittest along with coverage.py